# Duvida de Como realizar onChange em dois Selects

Tags: javascript, java

Gostaria de Saber qual a melhor forma de Realizar um onChange nos dois selects que possuo no meu form segue os selects:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group ${status.error ? has-error : '' }">
      <label for="listaContato" class="control-label"><spring:message
          code="ca_tipo_contato" /></label> <label
        class="listaContato control-label ${status.error ? has-error : ''}">
        <form:errors path="tipoContato" element="label" />
      </label>

      <form:select path="tipoContato" id="listaContato"
        data-placeholder="Contato" cssClass="form-control"
        cssStyle="width:100%;">
        <form:option value=""></form:option>
        <form:options items="${listaContato}"
          itemLabel="tipoContato" itemValue="id" />
      </form:select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group ${status.error ? has-error : '' }">
      <label for="listaDescricaoContato" class="control-label"><spring:message
          code="ca_descricao_contato" /></label> <label
        class="listaDescricaoContato control-label ${status.error ? has-error : ''}">
        <form:errors path="tipoDescricaoContato" element="label" />
      </label>

      <form:select path="tipoDescricaoContato"
        id="tipoDescricaoContato"
        data-placeholder="Descrição Contato"
        cssClass="form-control" cssStyle="width:100%;">
        <form:option value=""></form:option>
        <form:options items="${listaDescricaoContato}"
          itemLabel="tipoDescricaoContato"
          itemValue="id" />
      </form:select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

o TipoDescricão depende do TipoContato como faria para realizar esse onChange.

Comment: Wesley, explique o objetivo do sue código, ou seja, como essa tela deveria se comportar. Da forma que está sua pergunta não da para saber o que você quer.

Comment: A melhor e mais simples é colocando um onchange em cada um.

Comment: assim como o @ÐvÐ falou, basta você adicionar um atributo desta forma em cada select: `onchange="nomedafuncao()"` onde a função atrelada ao valor do atributo irá executar no momento em que o usuário mudar a opção do select em questão. Por isso basta declarar uma função javascript no seu arquivo .js e atribuir ela ao seu select através desta forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bom pessoal agradeço mais eu consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
   $( "#nomeSubStatusAnomalia" ).prop( "disabled", true );

            $("#nomeStatus").change(function () {
                    var StatusAnomalia = $("#nomeStatus").val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        type : 'GET',
                        url : '/cct/anomalia/changeSubStatusAnomalia/'+ StatusAnomalia,

                            beforeSend : function(xhr) {

                                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
                            },

                            success : function(response) {

                                console.log(response);


                                $.each(response, function(index, value){

                                    $("#nomeSubStatusAnomalia").append(

                                         '<option value='+ value.nomeSubStatusAnomalia +'>'+ value.nomeSubStatusAnomalia +'</option>'

                                    );

                               });

                            $( "#nomeSubStatusAnomalia" ).prop( "disabled", false );

                        },
                        error : function(response, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        }
                });

        });
```

montei esse ajax para atender as necessidades do meu formulario.

Answer (score -2):

```
    jQuery('#select1').change( function (e) {
        let valor = jQuery(e.target).val();
         if(valor == "usuario"){
            // select 2 com condição
            jQuery('select[name="tipo_usuario"]option').each(function(e) 
              {
                let texto = jQuery(this).text();
                //let valor = jQuery(this).val();
                if(texto.toLowerCase().trim() == "cliente"){
                    jQuery(this).attr("selected", true);
                }
            });
         }
    });
```